# What is the meaning of Vishnu maya in Tantrokta Devi Suktam?

Tags: devi, devi-bhagavata-purana

In tantrokta devi suktam, (durga saptashati) it has been mentioned as "Ya devi sarva bhuteshu Vishnumayeti shabdita....". What is "Vishnu maya" here?

Comment: It means that Durga is also represented as Maya of Vishnu. Actually a form of Durga; YogaMaya is the form which represents Maya of Vishnu. Read [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_003.html) of Harivamsha for details.

Comment: @Tezz You can post it as answer.